# How would a scientifically literate community manage forseeable malnutrition

Tags: science-based, biology, food

Assuming a roughly current level of scientific understanding, how would a small (<20) community manage a period of three months where they could only supply themselves with, on average, 800 kcal of energy a day (assuming otherwise nutritious food with no other major deficiencies to manage).

Would they consume their allotment daily, effectively going on "half rations", or would they eat a relatively full meal every other day? Which would lead to the best chance of making a full recovery after rescue?

Would that even be survivable, or would the community need to pick whom to supply and whom to let starve in order to have any chance of surviving at all? Are there any good resources about this sort of question?

Comment: Who are these people and who is in charge of food? Are they a group of friends, a professional team, or a group of random people? Please note that scientific literacy does not guarantee rationality and long-term planning ability.  The abovementioned information is necessary if your question is 'How a small group of people will most likely manage...?' However, if your question is 'What would be the optimal way to ration food in these conditions?', this information is irrelevant. I wonder if you could clarify this point.

Comment: On top of Otkin's point, how much of a forewarning do they have and what kind of technical resources? Right now, with a quick Google search, I got to the [Integrated Food Security Phase Classification website](http://www.ipcinfo.org/ipcinfo-website/ipc-overview-and-classification-system/en/) that has extensive technical material on how to deal with this type of crisis

Comment: Stealth removal of comments again? Those two comments were not answers but remarks intended to improve the q, in a different shape and form than Otkins did, but still. You wasting your time, others people time and bring misunderstanding in comment section, it is not helpfull for development of wb.

Comment: The event is foreseeable. To go into details, the idea is a space station that loses access to its base, and will need to survive for that amount of time until infrastructure can be restored.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. My comment was for that anonymous account which removed the comment(s) not belonging to it, if by a chance it would visit the comment section again. There were 2 comments - one is mine and one of another guy(AlexP). Both of those comments had no reason to be retracted, and I didn't remove mine. For you it may be "unsubstantiated accusations", no evidences provided(?) or I'm not sure what u meant by that. On my side however - it is the observable reality.

Comment: I will skip VTC for now. However, this question does need clarifications. If there are no edits with the requested information next time this query shows up in the review queue I will vote to close as needing details.

Comment: @MolbOrg OK, sorry, not sure what was going on.

Comment: This needs more detail, as noted, but it really isn't a story-based question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It'll be so easy they can do it in their sleep.

I've been on a similar diet. You'll mostly sleep through it.

When underfed and hungry and food can't be consumed, I find the desire to sleep or rest takes over.

Having tried a few extreme diets with very low KJ intakes, I can confirm the easiest way to survive on a very low KJ diet is to just not get out of bed. Sleep. Watch TV for a bit. Meander to the fridge and eat 50% of your sad rations. Drink a tonne of water. Meander back to bed. Sleep for a bit. Stumble to the toilet. Do a minor household chore. Go back to bed and try to sleep till afternoon. Do some paid work for your employer on a laptop. Drink some more water. Go sleep till evening. Eat the last 50% of your day's ration. Do some more paid work. Go to sleep.

1 kg of fat is 56,000kj. BMR (what you burn if you don't do anything) for a 30yr old male 180cm 80kg is 7,453kj. From pure maths, 7.5 days of starvation and you lose 1kg. You're not doing that - you're eating 3347kj per day. You're running a net loss of 4100kj a day, that's 1kg of fat every 13.6 days.

You'll lose 6.5kg of body fat over the 3 months. Your 80kg males (healthy BMI ~24.7) now weigh 73.5kg (also healthy BMI ~22.5).

Having tried a few fixed commercial diets and a few DIY ones, my suggestion if they can choose their food would be to favour maximum emotional satisfaction over nutrition or low GI or anything a scientists or doctor says - over only 3 months morale and compliance trump nutrition IMHO. I lost more weight, stuck to the diet better and longer, and was happier overall, when my KJ intake was spent on McDonald's Happy Meals than when it was spent on carefully crafted diet shakes or prepared meals, (even if I did have a rumbly tummy half the time, the morale boost from tasty food gave me something to look forward too.)

Comment: +1, 800 kcal/day is absolutely manageable for healthy people for 3 month IF those people can hunker down and reduce their physical activity. However, if they need to fight for their survival while on "third-rations", that will be another story.

Comment: The OP states in the comments that this is a space station. I wonder if it is possible to reduce activity to your suggested levels in this setting. I do not expect you to be able to answer this, though, since the OP does not provide enough details.

Comment: After re-reading your answer, I realised that you are talking only about males and do not mention sex differences. Women have lower body mass, higher body fat content, and a slower metabolism. There will be some differences between sexes in their response to this situation. On average, women should fare better and potentially have fewer psychological problems associated with the lack of nutrition.

Answer (score 0):

**You would calculate energy budgets.**

It would be just like calculating money budgets.  Your people are scientific and mathematic and this can be done in cool blood.

An example - suppose there is limited money to go around.  I have no money at all and need daily Starbucks and sushi, so I require 50 per day.  You also require sushi and fancy drinks but you have 5000 (in gold!) under your mattress which will pay your way so you need none of the limited money.  Ash, like me, has no money but he requires only a diet of dry beans and ramen, which he can buy for 5/day.  Everyone has their needs met according to those needs (expenses) and reserves (money under the mattress).

So too your people.  An individual with considerable on board caloric reserves (i.e. fat) and few caloric expenditures (physical work) can subsist on these reserves and vitamins; this individual will gradually cash in his caloric reserves.  A lean individual with few caloric reserves needs to have all caloric needs met with intake of calories.  An individual whose role requires physical work and consequent caloric expenditure needs to have that factored in too or she will not be able to do the work.  A child who needs additional calories for growth must have those needs met or he will stop growing.